JavaFX changes in Scene not updating on Hyper-V Windows VM after reconnect
I wrote a JavaFX-Application, that needs to run in different enviroments. In this paticular case, I noticed a bug when the program is used on a vm. When I start my program, everything works fine. But when I try to interact with it, after closing/disconnecting from the vm, the gui is not updating. I noticed, that the FX-Thread and all background-threads are still working. I can still resize the window and interact with the titlebar, but resizing results in a black color.
I'm using:

OpenJDK 19
OpenJFX 16
Hyper-V
VM: Windows 10

I found nothing wrong with my code, so I wrote a small program, to check, if the problem is related to JavaFX itself. The code I wrote for testing:
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ArchivApp extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        buildAndOpenStage(primaryStage);
    }

    private void buildAndOpenStage(Stage stage) {
        stage.setResizable(true);
        BorderPane bp = new BorderPane();
        TextField tf = new TextField("NewStage");
        stage.titleProperty().bind(tf.textProperty());
        bp.setCenter(tf);
        stage.setScene(new Scene(bp, 500, 500));

        tf.textProperty().addListener(ev -> {
            if (tf.textProperty().isEmpty().get()) {
            BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane(new Label("New Scene in old stage"));
            stage.setScene(new Scene(borderPane, 200, 200));
            stage.hide();
            stage.show();

            buildAndOpenStage(new Stage());
        }
    });

    stage.show();
    }
}

I bound the title of the stage to the textfield, to check if the application was still running/interactable. I also created a new stage, when the textfield is emptied (because I thought the problem could be related to the opened stage).
When I run the application, everything works fine. But if I keep the application opened, disconnect from the vm, reconnect to it, and interact with it, the gui is not updated anymore.
I attached a gif, which shows the strange behaviour:

Creating a new stage does also not fix the behaviour (Label should be shown, but nothing is displayed):

Things that seemed to work for me:
Using OpenJFX 21 instead of 16
or
Adding "-Dprism.order=sw" as an JVM argument
Is this a known bug, or am I overlooking something?
